# How to use a single IAM role to deploy resources in multiple accounts using CDK CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Is it possible to use a single IAM role (which can access another role) to deploy resources with environment variables `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION`?
For example: Below is a piece of code from Jenkinsfile , which uses a role to deploy resources in the account of which it a part.

```
script
{
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "sample-role-arn", variable: 'ARN'), string(credentialsId: "sample-role-extid", variable: 'EXT_ID')])
   {
     withAWS(role: "${ARN}", externalId: "${EXT_ID}", region: "${AWS_REGION}"){
       sh '''
       cdk deploy --all
       '''
       }
   }
}
```

In this code `sample-role-arn` is defined in the account in which `cdk deploy --all` will deploy the resources. If the `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` are set to different values of which `sample-role-arn` is not a part, the `cdk deploy --all` will through error: `Could not assume role in target account using current credentials (which are for account xxxxxx) User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/sample-role-arn/xxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource` is is expected.

However, if role is created in account set by `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` and made `sample-role-arn` as trusted entity, yet the same error as mentioned above is encountered despite the fact that `sample-role-arn` is a trusted entity.

Could someone please advise, if this is possible?